# Waiting for array to initialize with data from Firebase before calling methods

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Angular service that provides access to Firebase. I have a component in which I want to get the data from Firebase, put that information in an array, and then call some functions on that now initialized array. I'm new to Angular, so I'm not exactly sure how I should implement this behavior. I know subscribe() is asynchronous, and I need to implement my functions such that they are sensitive to this.

graph.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { EscortService } from '../services/escort/escort.service';
import { Escort } from '../data/escort.data';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph',
  templateUrl: './graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit {

       escortList : Escort[] = [];

        constructor(private escortService : EscortService, private element: ElementRef){
        } 

        ngOnInit(){
            this.getData();
            this.generateBarChart();
        }

        getData(){
            var esc = this.escortService.getData();
            esc.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
              this.escortList = [];
              item.forEach(element => {
                    var y = element.payload.toJSON();
                    y["$key"] = element.key;
                    var currentEscort = (y as Escort);
                    if(currentEscort.status == 'Completed'){
                        console.log("escort-list -> ngOnInit() : currentEscort.status = " + currentEscort.status);
                        this.escortList.push(currentEscort);
                     }
              });
           });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escortList should be Observable.

```
    private const escortList = new ReplaySubject<Escort[]>();
    get escortList() : Observable<Escort[]> {
        return this.escortList.asObservable();    // this prevents caller from being able to call method 'next' on the subject
    }

    constructor(private escortService : EscortService, private element: ElementRef){
    } 

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getData();
        this.generateBarChart();
    }

    getData(){
        var esc = this.escortService.getData();
        esc.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
          const newEscortList = [];
          item.forEach(element => {
                var y = element.payload.toJSON();
                y["$key"] = element.key;
                var currentEscort = (y as Escort);
                if(currentEscort.status == 'Completed'){
                    console.log("escort-list -> ngOnInit() : currentEscort.status = " + currentEscort.status);
                    newEscortList.push(currentEscort);
                 }
          });
          this.escortList.next(newEscortList);
       });
    }
```

And then, in your component, you just have to subscribe to the Observable to get updates. Don't forget to unsubscribe.

Comment: The compiler is telling me there's no .asobservable() function.

Comment: it was asObservable()

Comment: Thanks. I've never used these ReplaySubject objects before. Can I iterate through them?

Comment: You really should, angular is based on Observables, subjects,... You must understand it if you want to understand angular. Have a look at this : https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. What you need to do is put an `*ngIf` statement on the component in the app.component.html (or whatever element is directly above yours) checking whether the variable `is_loading` is equal to false. You can set the `is_loading` variable in your service, which is set to true on initialization, but to false once you have collected your data.
I hope this helps!